# How to export ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a few classes should be available as a npm package (name: technology-radar). But the user of the package usually only needs one class of the npm package (the Radar class).

If I import the Radar class from technology-radar and try to create an instance of this class I get the error `Object doesn't support this action`.

I am not sure if there is in exporting the class or in importing the class.
I am using webpack for bundeling and babel for ES6 support.

Radar.js

```
import ArgumentError from './ArgumentError';
import RadarRenderingEngine from './RadarRenderingEngine';
import Options from './Options';

export default class Radar { /* CONTENT HERE */ }
```

All other classes (ArgumentError, RadarRenderingEngine and Options) also use `export default class`. Is this correct?

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/Radar.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'technology-radar.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
                ],
                test: /\.js$/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [],
    devtool: "#source-map"
};
```

Is the webpack configuration correct?

Now I want to import the package in a client/test application.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mytest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --color",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "technology-radar": "^1.0.8"
  }
}
```

The file where I want to use the Radar:

```
import Radar from 'technology-radar';

var radar = new Radar();
radar.render();
```

---

EDIT:

This is the package.json of the technology-radar package:

```
{
  "name": "technology-radar",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "description": "This techradar has the goal that each company/department can create its own visualization of the trends to be focused on. To maintain the content of the techradar this one provides the possibility to dynamically add and edit the blips on the radar.",
  "main": "./dist/technology-radar.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "techradar",
    "d3.js"
  ],
  "author": "Raman Singh",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/raman-nbg/techradar",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "3.5.17"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/raman-nbg/techradar.git"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "src/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: are you using export default twice or more in a file, it is invalid

Comment: Could you add `package.json` for `technology-radar` package?

Comment: @WalleCyril I am ussing `export default` only once per file. But I am using it in each file.

Comment: @Bsalex I added the `package.json` for `technology-radar`